# I am not understding about this line [[ MyBook(string t,string a,int price):Book(t,a) ]] in C++ and How can I write this code in other way?

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance, c++17, virtual

I am almost new to the coding world. I am not able to understand the line `MyBook(string t,string a,int price):Book(t,a)` here, why is line is written, and how to write this line of code in a different way.

```
class Book{
    protected:
        string title;
        string author;
    public:
        Book(string t,string a){
            title=t;
            author=a;
        }
        virtual void display()=0;

};

// Write your MyBook class here
class MyBook : Book{
    private:
    int price;
    public:
    MyBook(string t,string a,int price):Book(t,a){
        this->price = price;
    }
    virtual void display(void) override {
        cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << author << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Darn. I was just about to remove my close-vote because of the updated question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int price) : Book(t,a) {
```

> why is line is written

This is a constructor that takes three arguments, `t`, `a`, and `price`. It initializes (`:` starts the member initializer list) the subobject `Book` by passing `t` and `a` to the `Book` constructor.

> and how to write this line of code in a different way.

The preferred way is to initialize both subobjects and member variables in the member initializer list:

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : Book(t,a), price{p} {
    // the body of the constructor can now be empty
}
```